# Kusto update policy: ExtentsMoveByQuery fails

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have created two update policy's that are run in a cascading manner and it worked fine. When I want to remove data from both of the source tables by setting a soft-delete period of 0s, the process seems to malfunction. Why?

I believe this error message is related:

> originalDestinationTables
>
> > Parameter name: Argument 'originalDestinationTables' failed to satisfy condition 'expected the distinct count of table names in both the following collections to be equal: extentsToReplaceByTableName with non empty addion lists, originalDestinationTables': at AddRemoveExtentsAsync in C:__w\1\s\Src\Engine\DataNode\Common\Entities\SchemaManager.cs: line 10742

Comment: Please provide repro steps that result with this error (i.e. All of the control commands you ran, in order)

Comment: @YoniL. The steps are:  **(1)** create table src_a, src_b, dest_c
**(2)**  set update policy a to be invoked on src_b, when data ingested into src_a
**(3)**  set update policy b to be invoked on dest_c, when data ingested into src_b
**(4)**  start streaming ingestion from Databricks into src_a: com.microsoft.azure.kusto:kusto-spark_3.0_2.12:3.1.11
**(5)**  Wait. See that data are flowing into tables. 
**(6)**  Set SoftDeletePeriod to 0s.

Comment: You do not need to investigate this on my account. I abandoned the cascading updates approach as it lead to this obscure error.